# Html + Javascript Undefined Function

Tags: javascript, html

JSFIDDLE for testing http://jsfiddle.net/8dw09y59/

Hey guys, I've tried everything.. Could someone please explain why i continue to get the "uncaught referenceerror: summonerLookUp is undefined"

I've tried switching the function to windows.summonerLookUp = function() { , but thats hasn't changed anything either. I've tried loading them within , within  I've tried loading it at the end of the document, but i get the error "In XHTML 1.0 Transitional the tag  cannot contain a tag ." is anyone able to explain whats going on here?

This is my index.js

```
function SummonerLookUp() {

var SumName
SumName = $("#SumInput").val();

if(SumName !== "") {

$.ajax({

url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + SumName + '?api_key=',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {

    },
 success: function (json) {
        var SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SumName.replace(" ", "");

        SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES.toLowerCase().trim();

        summonerLevel = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].summonerLevel;
        summonerID = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].id;

        document.getElementById("sLevel").innerHTML = summonerLevel;
        document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = summonerID;

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error getting Summoner data!");
    }
});
```

} else {}
}

and my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>LoLStats.GG</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Summoner Name
<br />
<input id="SumInput" />
<button onclick="summonerLookUp()">Click me</button>
<br />
<br />Summoner Level: <span id="sLevel"></span>

<br />Summoner ID: <span id="sID"></span>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Because your `onclick` is `summonerLookUp` with a lowercase `s` and your javascript is `SummonerLookUp` with a capital `S`

Comment: summonerLookUp != SummonerLookUp Just a caps issue

Comment: Good point :) Will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function SummonerLookUp is being called as summonerLookUp, javascript is case sensitive

Change

```
function SummonerLookUp() {
```

To

```
function summonerLookUp() {
```

Comment: I'd go the other way around and change the function name to `summonerLookUp` to follow standard javascript naming conventions

Comment: @BhavO i wish you knew how stupid i feel right now haha

Comment: Glad to help, mistakes happen, use the console output to see the errors, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. You named the function `SummonerLookUp`, but then you're trying to call `summonerLookUp`. Make them match.